# Make a batch that detects its own filepath

Tags: batch-file, directory, detect, filepath

I need to make a batch file that detects what drive and directory it is in. When I run the the file normally, it is in the correct directory/drive already. But when it is run as admin, it starts in system32. Is there a command that goes to the directory or drive the batch came from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
Pushd "%~dp0"
```

This changes the current directory to the path of the batch file.
Quoting the argument makes it safe against special characters in the pathname like "C:\Documents & Settings"

Comment: Wish I could upvote twice. Once for the correct answer regarding `%~dp0` and another for suggesting `pushd`. It's a very underused command and I always feel that using `cd` in an automation batch is just wrong :-)

Comment: Thanks, but at all it's a very simple answer. But you are right, it's an underused command, even in my own scripts I'm using `cd`

Comment: I try writing batches so that (at least in the successful case) the calling environment doesn't matter and will be restored as if the batch wasn't executes. Which means `setlocal` and `pushd` come in very handy. Might just be a habit of mine, though ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for both directories on c: and other drives.

Answer (score 0):

well a workaround is to use `\` before the path to give absolute path.

So, if you need to run a file `c:\temp\xyz.exe` and even if you are in directory `c:\winodws\system32` still when you do `cd \temp\xyz.exe` still the file will run properly